# Как достать значение с поля?

Tags: javascript

Какой самый лучший способ, чтобы достать значение с поля в Джаваскрипте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В образовательных целях лучше вообще не использовать jQuery

```
<input type="text" id="someId"  name="someName" />

//первый способ:
var v1 = document.getElementById('someId').value;
//второй способ:
var v2 = document.getElementsByName('someName')[0].value;
```

Comment: Следует добавить `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value`

Comment: document.forms['formName']['inputName'].value

Comment: Тогда уж более красиво `document.forms['formName'].elements['inputName'].value`
Но в случае с select, checkbox и radio-button кода будет по-больше...

Answer (score 1):

Самый быстрый способ - задать id и доставать значение через `document.getElementById(...).value`.
Также, можно использовать и `getElementsByName`, но name обычно соответствует id.

Comment: Только `id` предполагается уникальным, а `name` - нет

Comment: Это само собой разумеется. И из названия функции getElementsByName можно понять, что возвращается массив (список элементов).

Comment: но из `getElementById` не понять, что он вернёт ( тест в chrome ) первый элемент с таким ID

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как самый лучший, но например так (если вы подразумеваете, что поле это input):

```
jQuery("#get_data_target").attr("value")
```

get_data_target - id элемента, откуда берём значение

Comment: так можно сразу писать .val()

Comment: согласен, но думаю, в образовательных целях нужно ещё показать, откуда берётся значение.

Comment: Поддержу @makregistr если уж jQuery, тогда уж лучше `.val()`